# How to create a disk image located in asia,eu,us regions?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Several of Google Cloud Platform's pre-built disk images have their location set to *asia,eu,us*.

[image: Pre-built images with asia,eu,us location]

**However, I have not been able to set the location to *asia,eu,us* for my own disk images**.

The documentation for [`gcloud compute images create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/create#--storage-location) says:

> #### `--storage-location=LOCATION`
>
> Specifies a Cloud Storage location, either regional or multi-regional, where image content is to be stored. If not specified, the multi-region location closest to the source is chosen automatically.

However, using the `--storage-location=` flag, I've only been able to set it to a single multi-region, like *us*.

#### Context

I want to avoid [intercontinental egress](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing) every time I boot a VM in Europe or Asia using a disk image I authored in a US region. Rather, want to pay the intercontinental egress cost once when I author the disk image, and then benefit from same zone/same region egress pricing for each VM boot.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to verify this yet, but seems like the REST API might support multiple storage locations per image: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#api

Answer (score 1):

A good workaround would be to create a disk snapshot and save it in different regions, you can then use those to spin up new vms from the snapshots. So essentially you would take a snapshot of your existing vm and save it in a different region. Once that is done, you can go to your snapshots that you have saved in different regions and create an instance from the snapshot, thus eliminating cross region egress. Please view this documentation for further instructions[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The image lives in a GCS bucket and its location is restricted to regions and multi-regions that a bucket can be assigned to.

From [Creating a Custom Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#creating_a_custom_image):

> ### Selecting an image storage location
>
> When creating a custom image, you can specify the image's [Cloud
>   Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations) location, excluding dual-region locations. By specifying the
>   image storage location, you can meet your regulatory and compliance
>   requirements for data locality as well as your high availability needs
>   by ensuring redundancy across regions.
>
> The storage location feature is optional. If you do not select a
>   location, Compute Engine stores your image in the multi-region closest
>   to the image source.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google compute images create API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/insert) endpoint takes a list of strings but has validation to only permit 1 item.
If you try pass more than one location you receive a 400 response with the following error message.

```
{
  "message": "Value for field 'resource.storageLocations' is too large: maximum size 1 element(s); actual size 2.",
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "fieldSizeTooLarge"
}
```